# Gradle: Multiple Flavors, each having both Staging & Production endpoints

Tags: android, gradle

Mostly we pass the REST endpoint through the `buildConfigField` in the flavor configuration, like this:

```
buildFlavors {

   staging {
     buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_URL", "\"http://staging-server.com\""
   }

   production {
     buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_URL", "\"http://production.com\""
   }

}
```

This is well understood.

---

Now imagine a Car Dashboard application. We have a single project, and three **customers**, or `productFlavors`:

- `Audi`
- `Bentley`
- `Chevrolet`

For each flavor, we have 2 different server configurations:

- `Staging`
- `Production`

and of course, two `buildTypes`:

- `Debug`
- `Release`.

---

Now, for each variant, we have different REST endpoints:

- `Audi`

  - `Staging` : `staging.audi.com`
  - `Production` : `audi-live.com`
- `Bentley`

  - `Staging` : `bentleystaging.com`
  - `Production` : `bproduction.com`
- `Chevrolet`

  - `Staging` : `chev-staging.com`
  - `Production` : `prod-chevy.com`

---

### Here's the problem:

Now, how can we declare the Flavors and Endpoint configurations together in the `build.gragle` so that we can build two APKs for each of the customers above, with `Staging` and `Production` configurations?

Something like this:

- **Debug builds:**
- `AudiStagingDebug`   - Customer: `Audi`, Config: `Staging`.
- `AudiProductionDebug` - Customer: `Audi`, Config: `Production`.
- `BentleyStagingDebug`
- `BentleyProductionDebug`
- `ChevroletStagingDebug`
- `ChevroletProductionDebug`
- **Release builds:**
- `AudiStagingRelease`
- `AudiProductionRelease`
- `BentleyStagingRelease`
- `BentleyProductionRelease`
- `ChevroletStagingRelease`
- `ChevroletProductionDebug`

Comment: Similar question, but doesn't answer this particular case - https://stackoverflow.com/q/30660426/816416

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at Flavor Dimensions?  The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#flavor-dimensions) isn't terribly clear, in my opinion.  But this series of articles might help, particularly: [Advanced Android Flavors Part 2 — Enter Flavor Dimensions](https://proandroiddev.com/advanced-android-flavors-part-2-enter-flavor-dimensions-4ad7f486f6)

Comment: Checked the flavor dimensions already. Of course we can add a "server" dimension, but it doesn't allow supplying Staging/Production links for each `flavorDimension` build variant.

Comment: Anyway thanks for the article link, it sheds some light into a possible solution, I will check and come back with it.