# Android Studio - productFlavor combinations to set version

Tags: build.gradle, versioning, android-productflavors, android-build-flavors, android-flavordimension

In my `build.gradle`, I'm defining 2 different flavor dimensions:

```
//list flavorDimensions in override priority order
flavorDimensions 'flavor', 'platform'

//assign each productFlavor a corresponding flavorDimension
productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
        dimension 'flavor'
        applicationId "com.flavor1"
    }
    flavor2 {
        dimension 'flavor'
        applicationId "com.flavor2"
    }
    mobile {
        dimension 'platform'
        applicationIdSuffix '.mobile'
        minSdkVersion 22
    }
    tv {
        dimension 'platform'
        applicationIdSuffix '.tv'
        minSdkVersion 21
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to set `versionCode` and `versionName` based on the combinations, so each of the following could have it's own version info:

- flavor1Mobile

  - versionName = 1.0.0
  - versionCode = 3
- flavor1Tv

  - versionName = 1.0.2
  - versionCode = 5
- flavor2Mobile

  - versionName = 3.0.0
  - versionCode = 10
- flavor2Tv

  - versionName = 2.0.0
  - versionCode = 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to build a solution by combining the solutions from :

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/30880966
- https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips#configure-dynamic-version-codes

  ```
  project.ext{

      flavor1Mobile_versionName = "1.0.0"
      flavor1Mobile_versionCode = 3

      flavor1Tv_versionName = "1.0.2"
      flavor1Tv_versionCode = 5


      flavor2Mobile_versionName = "3.0.0"
      flavor2Mobile_versionCode = 10

      flavor2Tv_versionName = "2.0.0"
      flavor2Tv_versionCode = 4

  }


  project.android.applicationVariants.all {variant ->
      def versionName = project.ext."${variant.flavorName}_versionName"
      def versionCode = project.ext."${variant.flavorName}_versionCode"
      variant.outputs.each { output ->
          output.versionNameOverride = versionName
          output.versionCodeOverride = versionCode
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem and was able to solve it a little bit different, but depending on the circumstances of future visitors of this page, it may help.

In your global gradle.properties file you can define your different versions:

```
flavor1_versionName=1.0.0
flavor2_versionName=1.2.3
mobile_versionName=1.0.1
tv_versionName=1.0.2
```

Then you can just override the versionName parameter in your build.gradle(:app) file where you add your productFlavors:

```
productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
        dimension 'flavor'
        applicationId "com.flavor1"
        versionName = flavor1_versionName;
    }
    flavor2 {
        dimension 'flavor'
        applicationId "com.flavor2"
        versionName = flavor2_versionName;
    }
    mobile {
        dimension 'platform'
        applicationIdSuffix '.mobile'
        minSdkVersion 22
        versionName = mobile_versionName;
    }
    tv {
        dimension 'platform'
        applicationIdSuffix '.tv'
        minSdkVersion 21
        versionName = tv_versionName;
    }
}
```

In your defaultConfig block in the same build.gradle file, you can say:

```
versionName version
project.version version
```